# Firebase Messaging: Send a data message to all app users with a cloud function

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

How could I approach messaging all users of an app? 
With the web GUI it is possible to send a notification message to all users of an app, so I assume doing the same with a function and a data message (or at least with a notification message) is possible with a function too - but I couldn't find a way to do that.

#### My Attempt

I tried subscribing all devices to a topic, by calling:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");
```

In the `onCreate` event of my `FirebaseMessagingService`, then sending a message with a cloud function:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref("/messages/{meta}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const message = snapshot._data;
        console.log("msg", message["title"]);
        // logs the correct data, therefore the event triggers
        const payload = {
            data: {
                title: message["title"]
                /* blah blah */
            },

            topic: "all"
        }

        admin.database().ref("/messages/" + context.params.meta).remove()
        return admin.messaging().send(payload)
    })
```

But `onMessageReceived` doesn't trigger (unlike when I send a notification message using the GUI). 
Is this approach viable in any way? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only part you will need to change is the end. You won't need this part here `admin.database().ref("/messages/" + context.params.meta).remove()`.

For the messaging, your code needs to look something like the below sample:

```
// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().send(payload)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

You need to user a catch to manage the error - this way you will be able to visualize as well, what might be causing your issue. You can find more information in this documentation here: [Send messages to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics).

Besides that, I found this nice repository - that you can access [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) - with some examples and more code samples, on how to use Cloud Functions with FCM.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one thing: the line u mentioned is meant to delete the message from the db after sending it. I know I don't need it for the messaging part, but is there a problem with having it?

Comment: Hi @OmerLubin thanks for clarifying that line! If you are using this only to delete from the db, it should not affect you, but I would give it a try removing this line as well as changing the way you are sending the message, just for the sake of testing.

Comment: Just in case anyone looks this up, the bug happened to be unrelated to Firebase Messaging, and related to code I ommited - the code in the question works perfectly. Proper logging, as shown in this answer, is what got me to find it.